# Method of undetermined coefficients for nonhomogeneous linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me to understand how to obtain the complementary functions of the three following ODEs, please?

1. $y''+4y'+4y=4x^2+6e^x$ (the complementary function is $y=(c_1+c_2x)e^{-2x}$)
2. $y''-3y'+2y=2x^2+3e^{2x}$ (the complementary function is $y=c_1e^{x}+c_2e^{2x}$)
3. $y''+4y'+4y=3xe^{2x}$ (the complementary function is $y=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}$)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean a particular solution?

Comment: No, I need to identify the complementary function to see how it compares to the RHSs and solve accordingly

Comment: **Hints:** $$m^2 + 4 m + 4 = 0 \\ m^2 - 3 m + 2 = 0$$

Comment: @Moo, I got it, thx!